# Display sum of a column(as total) on a datatable and export to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am exporting a datatable as excel file with 4 columns, out of that my column 3 contains product prices, now after the export, I should see an additional row at the end of the table with "Total" and contains the sum of column 3 values.

I thought of showing it on the datatable using footercallback and export the datatable directly, but as I am using multi filter in the footer section and can't create one more footer this idea didn't work.

Expectation: Show the sum of a column-3(filtered) on the html page near to datatable saying that when I export as excel it should contain the summation value at the end of the table rows.

Comment: Add total as hidden column to datatable. When you export datatable it will also have hidden column values

Comment: My requirement is to add a *row" as total which would give the Sum of the product prices @sangita

Comment: Please share more details with some code sample to understand better

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    var len=$("tr").length;

    var sum=0;

    for(var i=1;i<len;i++){
      sum += parseFloat($("tr td").eq(2).html());
    }

    $("table").createElement("<tr><td></td><td></td><td>"+sum+"</td></tr>");
```

Comment: since you are adding column 3, that is why `eq(2)`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need total of all prices for each product. You can have total as hidden column in datatable. When you do excel export it will show total. Here is sample html and javascript code. Hope this might help you.

HTML

```
<table class="table display" id="table2" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price </th>
                <th>Tax</th>
                <th>Shipping Charges</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Product1</th>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>132</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Product2</th>
                <td>234</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Product3</th>
                <td>543</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>620</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
  $('#table2').dataTable({


            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "columnDefs": [

            {
                "targets": [ 4 ],
                "visible": false
            }
        ],
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'excel',
                filename : 'test',

            }]
        });
```

Comment: Per the code, it already has the "total" column with data in it but my need is to dynamically calculate the sum of the prices for all the products and show it as a row "total" in the datatable. Meaning I will have a single row total which keeps updating based on my filtered products.